# Typing is extremely sluggish/choppy after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, text, input

Last night I upgraded to 14.04. Since then, typing text has been almost unbearably unresponsive. Double letters often pop up, while letters are skipped at other times. The worst happens in Terminal, where Terminal starts darkening and becoming unresponsive. It takes 2-3 times the amount of time to do anything because of the lag, regardless of the application.

I've tried reinstalling the input driver using "sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics". No luck.

Answer (score 0):

can you please go into details from dash and check the graphics  driver?
I think it has to do with your graphics driver.

I think you should add this ppa 
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/x-updates

I hope you know how to add a ppa, sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

and then after sudo apt-get update 
run sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
I hope it will be ok by then.

Comment: I'm using a Radeon HD 3450 graphics card. It lists "Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620." I imagine that's not correct?

Comment: Your graphics card is a legacy one, please follow the steps I have mentioned